# Can a single query handle possible if statements

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Can a single query do this

```
Schedule::where('location_id', $this->location_id)      //if result found do nothing else

      // but if no result found then evaluate
      wherisNull(location_id)
```

Comment: What else are you wanting to query after the `// but if no result found then evaluate`? I ask because I wonder if there is a way to formulate the query with an or where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, multiple conditional queries can be avoided by these steps.

1. Store result of the query in a variable. The result is a collection.
2. Use the where and other collection helpers to constraint the collection.

A single query and collection helpers can do the trick.

This is how I did.

**The query**

```
$appointment_at = $this->appointment_at;

    if(request()->ismethod("Post") || request()->ismethod("Patch")) {
      $schedules = Schedule::whereHas('dayTimes', function ($query) use ($appointment_at) {
         $query->where('start_time', '<=', $appointment_at->format('H:m'))
          ->where('end_time', '>=', $appointment_at->format('H:m'));
        })
        ->whereDate('start_date', '<=', $appointment_at)
        ->whereDate('end_date', '>=', $appointment_at)
      ->get();
    }
```

**Use of collection helpers**

```
    if(empty($this->location_id) && empty($this->service_id) && empty($this->user_id)) {
        $schedule = $schedules;
    }
    else if(!empty($this->location_id) && empty($this->service_id) && empty($this->user_id)) {
      $schedule = $schedules->where('location_id', $this->location_id);

      if(! $schedule->count()) {
        $schedule = $schedules->whereNull('location_id');
      }
    }
    else if(empty($this->location_id) && !empty($this->service_id) && empty($this->user_id)) {
      $schedule = $schedules->where('service_id', $this->service_id);

      if(! $schedule->count()) {
        $schedule = $schedules->whereNull('service_id');
      }
    }
    else if(empty($this->location_id) && empty($this->service_id) && !empty($this->user_id)) {
      $schedule = $schedules->where('user_id', $this->user_id);

      if(! $schedule->count()) {
        $schedule = $schedules->whereNull('user_id');
      }
    }
    else if(!empty($this->location_id) && !empty($this->service_id) && empty($this->user_id)) {
      $schedule = $schedules->where('location_id', $this->location_id)->where('service_id', $this->service_id);

      if(! $schedule->count()) {
        $schedule = $schedules->where('location_id', $this->location_id)->whereNull('service_id');
      }

      if(! $schedule->count()) {
        $schedule = $schedules->whereNull('location_id');
      }
    }
    else if(!empty($this->location_id) && empty($this->service_id) && !empty($this->user_id)) {
      $schedule = $schedules->where('location_id', $this->location_id)->where('user_id', $this->user_id);

      if(! $schedule->count()) {
        $schedule = $schedules->where('location_id', $this->location_id)->whereNull('user_id');
      }

      if(! $schedule->count()) {
        $schedule = $schedules->whereNull('location_id');
      }
    }
    else if(empty($this->location_id) && !empty($this->service_id) && !empty($this->user_id)) {
      $schedule = $schedules->where('service_id', $this->service_id)->where('user_id', $this->user_id);

      if(! $schedule->count()) {
        $schedule = $schedules->where('service_id', $this->service_id)->whereNull('user_id');
      }

      if(! $schedule->count()) {
        $schedule = $schedules->whereNull('service_id');
      }
    }
    else if(!empty($this->location_id) && !empty($this->service_id) && !empty($this->user_id)) {
      $schedule = $schedules->where('location_id', $this->location_id)->where('service_id', $this->service_id)->where('user_id', $this->user_id);

      if(! $schedule->count()) {
        $schedule = $schedules->where('location_id', $this->location_id)->where('service_id', $this->service_id)->whereNull('user_id');
      }

      if(! $schedule->count()) {
        $schedule = $schedules->where('location_id', $this->location_id)->whereNull('service_id')->whereNull('user_id');
      }

      if(! $schedule->count()) {
        $schedule = $schedules->whereNull('location_id');
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `exists()` can help here.

```
$schedule = Schedule::where('location_id', $this->location_id);

if(!$schedule->exists()){
   unset($query->where('location_id'));
   $schedule->wherisNull('location_id');
}

$schedule->get();
```

Comment: .I will have to do similar checks for service_id, user_id, and various combinations. These will result in multiple queries. So I need to do this in a single query if this is possible.

Comment: Here always need some conditions. The above one is one query but still, conditions are there. You can use raw queries but here you need to manage the cases which are also conditions. You can't guess the query has data or not without execute it. So, you always need to make conditions it's up to you, how you will make them. In PHP or SQL using raw queries.

Comment: There is no `$query->wheres`. If ·$query· is the instance of query-builder, you cannot directly access it by `$schedule`, because it is a protected property. And if you can remove the `where('location_id', $this->location_id)` condition. The code still run two sql. Because one of that is `select exists(select * from schedule where location_id = ?) as exists`. the other is `select * from ...whereNull` or `select * from where location_id = ? limit 1 `